# Modal not showing when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need help to display a modal using ajax. I already have my code but when the button is clicked, the modal does not display. The fading is shown but no modal is appearing.

Here is my button and modal

```
<button class="btnView" data-target="#myModal" role="button">View Details</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Under, I have this script that will get what's inside view_modal.php and put it inside the modal-content class.

```
$(".btnView").click(function(){
       if(ID!=""){
              $.ajax
              ({
               type: "POST",
               url: "view_modal.php",
               cache: false,
               success: function(html)
               {
                  $(".modal-content").html(html);
               } 
               });
        }else{
            $('.modal-content').html("<div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' id='btnClosemodal' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button><h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Select Record</h4></div><br/><center>Please select a record first before clicking view button.</center><br/>");
        }
       $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
```

This is the view_modal.php

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" id="btnClosemodal" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View Details</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="form1" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Title:</p>
            <p>Message:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnClosemodal" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">CLOSE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't explain in your post or the tags what kind of modal you're using. A JavaScript plugin?

Comment: just check if your modal is updated with new html.If yes than there is something wrong with your css.Logic looks perfect

Comment: I guess this is Bootstrap, right?  Does `$('.modal').modal();` (without 'show') work?  If you view source in dev tools, has your content been added to the modal?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the button,

```
<button id="btnAdd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn-group-sm btn-primary" value="Search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Add New</span></button>
```

This is the html to display a Modal,

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" name="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```